# Error en consulta por rango de fechas

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Buenas tardes compañeros.

Tengo una consulta por rango de fechas en laravel que me trae de cabeza. Inicialmente la consulta funciona sin errores pero he detectado que si el rango de fechas es entre años distintos (12-2020 a 01-2021) no me devuelve ningún registro. Estoy un poco cansado de revisar el código y no veo el problema.

Os pongo aquí la consulta y la comprobación que hago para aplicar el filtro de las fechas antes de devolver los valores para ver si me podéis indicar por dónde puede venir el error.

Consulta:

```
public function getData($filters) {

    $tasks = $this->getModel()
        ->whereIn('tasks.department_id', $filters['departmentIds'])
        ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'tasks.department_id')
        ->join('deliverables as dev', 'dev.id', '=', 'tasks.deliverable_id')
        ->leftJoin('deliverables as sub', 'sub.id', '=', 'tasks.subdeliverable_id')
        ->leftJoin('workers as st_workers', 'st_workers.id', '=', 'tasks.start_worker_id')
        ->leftJoin('workers as end_workers', 'end_workers.id', '=', 'tasks.end_worker_id')
        ->leftJoin('type_task_statuses', 'type_task_statuses.id', '=', 'tasks.status_id')
        ->leftJoin('incidences', 'incidences.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
        ->select('tasks.id', 'departments.name as department', 'tasks.start_worker_id', 'tasks.end_worker_id', 'st_workers.short_name as start_worker',
        'end_workers.short_name as end_worker', 'tasks.plane', 'tasks.st', 'dev.name as deliverable', 'sub.name as subdeliverable',
            'tasks.quantity', 'tasks.other_deliverable', 'tasks.start_prevision_date', 'tasks.end_prevision_date', 'tasks.start_date',
            'tasks.end_date', 'tasks.prevision_hour', 'tasks.incurred_hour', 'type_task_statuses.display_name as status', 'type_task_statuses.color', 'tasks.advance', 'tasks.agreed',
            'tasks.disagreed_date', 'tasks.supervised', DB::raw('COUNT(incidences.id) as count_incidences'))
        ->groupBy('tasks.id');

    if (array_key_exists('fromDate', $filters) && $filters['fromDate']) {
        $tasks->whereRaw('(DATE_FORMAT(tasks.end_date, "%m-%Y") >= "'.$filters['fromDate'].'" OR tasks.end_date is NULL)');
    }
    if (array_key_exists('toDate', $filters) && $filters['toDate']) {
        $tasks->whereRaw('(DATE_FORMAT(tasks.end_date, "%m-%Y") <= "'.$filters['toDate'].'" OR tasks.end_date is NULL)');
    }

    return $tasks;
}
```

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato son las columnas involucradas?

Comment: La columna involucrada para el filtro por fechas es END_DATE y es de tipo DATE.

Comment: Query Builder tiene una cláusula `whereDate` que creo que podrías usar. No entiendo bien cuál es la lógica del filtro, ni el porqué de ese formato que aplicas, pero algo más "in the laravel way" podría ser `$tasks->where(function($query){ $query->whereDate('tasks.end_date', '>=', $filters['fromDate'])->orWhereNull('tasks.end_date') });`

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia porlocerros, pero al cambiar la consulta me da un error de clase desconocida.